# I can't 'passthrough' a step in sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I wanted to test different `scaler` in my `pipeline`, so I created a `class` that can take as parameter the `scaler` I want (Standard, MinMax etc..)

It works fine. But i want to specifiy in my `param_grid` to test without scaler. And I added 'passthrough' in my pipeline estimators, but it doesn't work and i get the following error :

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set_params'

I know it might have something to do with the construction of my class but i can't find how to fix it.

Here is the code you can run to test.

```
# import dependencies
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, RobustScaler   
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

import pandas as pd

class ScalerSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self, scaler=StandardScaler()):
        super().__init__()
        self.scaler = scaler

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self.scaler.fit(X)

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return self.scaler.transform(X)


data = load_breast_cancer()
features = data["data"]
target = data["target"]
data = pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=data['feature_names'])
col_names = data.columns.tolist()

# scaler and encoder options
my_scaler = ScalerSelector()

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('numerical', my_scaler, col_names)
                                                ])

# combine the preprocessor with LogisticRegression() using Pipeline 
full_pipeline = Pipeline(steps = [('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                                  ('log_reg', LogisticRegression())
                                  ])

# set params combination I want to try
scaler_options = {'preprocessor': ['passthrough'],
                  'preprocessor__numerical__scaler':[StandardScaler(), RobustScaler(), MinMaxScaler()]}
# : ['passthrough', ScalerSelector()]
# initialize GridSearchCV using full_pipeline as final estimator
grid_cv = GridSearchCV(full_pipeline, param_grid = scaler_options)

# fit the data 
grid_cv.fit(data, target)

# best params :
grid_cv.best_params_
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Tracebak") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you should remove all this preprocesor from options. Or maybe you should use empty list without `'passthrough'` because it try to do `'passthrough'.set_params`

Comment: For me the problem here is not really that you are not able to 'passthrough' a step as this seems to be correctly set, but it is rather in the use of `preprocessor__numerical__scaler` option; look at what happens if you only use a dictionary with `'preprocessor'` as key and `['passthrough', StandardScaler(), ...]` as values.